# I accidently deleted the /var directory from my Ubuntu 16.10 system. How to recover those files?

Tags: boot, error-handling

I accidently deleted the /var directory from my Ubuntu 16.10 system. Now when I restart the computer ,it displays an error showing my computer is running on low graphics! And after I hit enter it shows a few option but none is working out for me. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible dupe? [How to restore accidentlly deleted /var folder in Ubuntu installation?](http://superuser.com/questions/355401/how-to-restore-accidentlly-deleted-var-folder-in-ubuntu-installation)

Comment: You should reinstall Ubuntu from scratch - it will take less time than all attempts to repair the system - too many things are completely broken after you've deleted the `/var` folder which contains a lot of important stuff. :)

Comment: adding to boxy's comment: reinstall WITHOUT a format. It will keep your settings and systems and will install /var for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CD of Ubuntu try to copy that /var folder into your computer.

> However , I am not sure whether this will work or not:(